# Unable to send auth token to server axios

Tags: node.js, vue.js, express, axios, vuejs3

I am trying to set up a simple login system for a small project. I have managed to connect the website to an login api hosted locally via mysql database.
I'm using express/nodejs on backend and Vue for front end. Also using axios to send http requests.

The error i get is POST http://localhost:3001/api/get-user 422 (Unprocessable Entity)
"{"message":"Please provide the token"}"
Client side part of code.

```
            finally{
            const auth = await axios.post(`/api/get-user`, {
                headers: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${this.Token}` 
                }
            })
        }
```

Server side part.

```
router.post('/get-user', signupValidation, (req, res, next) => {


if(
    !req.headers.authorization ||
    !req.headers.authorization.startsWith('Bearer') ||
    !req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1]
){
    return res.status(422).json({
        message: "Please provide the token",
    });
}

const theToken = req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1];
const decoded = jwt.verify(theToken, 'the-super-strong-secrect');

db.query('SELECT * FROM users where id=?', decoded.id, function (error, results, fields) {
    if (error) throw error;
    return res.send({ error: false, data: results[0], message: 'Fetch Successfully.' });
});
```

});

I have put a base URL.
The login is working 100% and I am able to extract the token from the response data.
I used Postman to send the request to the server to get the user and it works perfectly. I believe the issue is in the code of the client side or maybe the client side is sending the token incorrectly where the server side cant read it... I'm not sure please help.

Comment: What's the problem? What goes wrong?

Comment: I get the error "{\"message\":\"Please provide the token\"}", POST http://localhost:3001/api/get-user 422 (Unprocessable Entity)

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/EcYTfpn This is what I get in in network tab under payload, so i know my token is sent out but I have no idea why its not being received by the server.

Comment: Posted the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second parameter in axios post is the body

```
 finally{
            const auth = await axios.post(`/api/get-user`,{}, {
                headers: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${this.Token}` 
                }
            })
        }
```

Comment: You are a genius my friend, I tried to google for ages but no idea it was a parameter issue. Thank you very much!

Comment: Feel free to accept answer too :D